# Find the dividend when remainder is given

Tags: java, encryption

I have written a program in which I'm encrypting user input. The input is only four digit long. The encryption formula is as follow:

1. Ask user to enter 4 digits
2. iterate those one by one and add 7 into those.
3. Get remainder of each number by dividing by 10.
4. swap 1 with 3 and 2 with 4.

suppose I have entered 1234. After adding the number 7 in each digit, the number looks like 891011. The remainder of these number are 8901. Now I swap those and the final number looks like 0189.This is all about the encrypted program.

```
USER INPUT : 0189
```

Now I have to write another separate program which decrypt user's input and find out the actual number. The problem I'm facing is, I have to find the dividend first. But given data I have only is divisor and remainder (In this case 10 and 0). Please guide me if I'm wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The translation table doesn't show any duplicate, so no problem here:

```
n    +7   %10
--------------
0 =>  7 => 7
1 =>  8 => 8
2 =>  9 => 9
3 => 10 => 0
4 => 11 => 1
5 => 12 => 2
6 => 13 => 3
7 => 14 => 4
8 => 15 => 5 
9 => 16 => 6
```

So to decrypt:

- unshuffle the digits
- subtract 7 on each digit and if the result is negative add 10 (or use a translation table)

Answer (score 2):

Let do some calculation:

- Each of the original digit ranges from 0 to 9.
- After add 7, each will range from 7 to 16.
- After divided by 10, any number ranges from 7 to 9 will be the same; any x number ranges from 10 to 16 will range from 0 to 6.
- To find the original, for each of the final digit, do

  `if (x <= 6)  original = x + 10 - 7;
  if (x > 6) original = x - 7;`

Answer (score 1):

I tried it using a simple program in JAVA and had no problems.

Here is the code snippet if you want to give it a shot:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    /* Start Encrypting */
    String encrypted = encrypt(in.nextInt(), 4);
    System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
    /* Start Decrypting */
    String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, 4);
    System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decrypted);
}

/* Encryption Logic */
public static String encrypt(int x, int size) {
    int[] output = new int[size];
    /* Add 7, Mod 10 Logic */
    for(int i = size - 1; x > 0; i--) {
        output[i] = ((x % 10) + 7) % 10; 
        x /= 10;
    }
    /* Swap Logic */
    for(int i = 0; i < size/2; i++) {
        int temp = output[i];
        output[i] = output[i+2];
        output[i+2] = temp;
    }
    /* Return Result */
    return Arrays.toString(output).replace(", ","").substring(1,size+1);
}

/* Decryption Logic */
public static String decrypt(String x, int size) {
    /* Get Chars */
    char[] input = x.toCharArray();
    int[] output = new int[size];
    /* Sub 7, Mod 10 Logic */
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output[i] = (((int)(input[i]) - 48) + 3) % 10;
    }
    /* Swap Logic */
    for(int i = 0; i < size/2; i++) {
        int temp = output[i];
        output[i] = output[i+2];
        output[i+2] = temp;
    }
    /* Return Result */
    return Arrays.toString(output).replace(", ","").substring(1,size+1);
}
```

Input:

```
1234
```

Output:

```
Encrypted: 0189
Decrypted: 1234
```